# Apache nifi 1.19.0 failed to start

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to start nifi 1.19.0 with docker image.
I use this command (I get it from dockerhub website).

```
docker run --name nifi \
  -p 8443:8443 \
  -d \
  apache/nifi:1.19.0
```

But it failed to start.

Here is the log:

```
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /home/nifi/.nifi-cli.nifi.properties
replacing target file  /home/nifi/.nifi-cli.nifi.properties
replacing target file  /home/nifi/.nifi-cli.nifi.properties
replacing target file  /home/nifi/.nifi-cli.nifi.properties
replacing target file  /home/nifi/.nifi-cli.nifi.properties
NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST was not set but NiFi is configured to run in a secure mode. The NiFi UI may be inaccessible if using port mapping or connecting through a proxy.
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
replacing target file  /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
NiFi running with PID 40.
tail: cannot open '/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs/nifi-app.log' for reading: No such file or directory

Java home: /opt/java/openjdk
NiFi home: /opt/nifi/nifi-current

Bootstrap Config File: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/bootstrap.conf

[0.003s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "GC Thread#0" - pthread_create failed (EPERM) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 4k, detached.
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Cannot create worker GC thread. Out of system resources.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/nifi/nifi-current/hs_err_pid40.log
```

I didn't have any problem with previous version. In new version they change java version from 8 to 11. Maybe the issue is related to this change.

Comment: Hi dear Sajad. There is an issue with your resource. Java GC can't start any thread. Have you enough free memory?

Comment: I found the the cause of problem. I had to delete all the volume before start the container.